Lightning Network Saturated Channels Percentage
I'm interested in knowing if there has been any research on calculating the percentage of saturated channels in the Lightning Network. While I understand the network's dynamic nature and how frequently it changes, I would expect the saturation rate of channels to remain relatively consistent over time.
